# Existence of a continuous linear functional with $f(x_0)=||x_0||$ and $ \sup\{|f(x)|:x\in X,x\neq 0\}=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let X be a linear, real or complex normed space and let $x_0\in X,x_0\neq0$. Show that: It exists a continous 
linear functional $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$ where $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb R,\mathbb C$ s.t :$$ f(x_0)=||x_0||$$$$ \sup\{|f(x)|:x\in X,x\neq 0\}=1$$

My problem is next:
We must show existence , if it exists a continous linear functional $f$ which respect above conditions then:

$f(x_0+x_0+...x_0)=f(x_0)+f(x_0)+...f(x_0)=||x_0||+||x_0||+...||x_0||=n||x_0||$ ($n$ terms)

Let $y_0=x_0+x_0+...x_0$ then $n||x_0||=f(y_0)\leq \sup\{|f(x)|:x\in X,x\neq 0\}=1$ so $n||x_0||\leq 1 ,\forall n\geq1$ but then $||x_0||=0 $ and this is a contradiction with $x_0\neq0$

Comment: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/corollaries-to-the-hahn-banach-theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x_0 \neq 0$, $\{x_0\}$ can be completed into a basis $\mathcal B= \{x_0\} \cup \{x_i \mid i \in I\}$ of $X$.

Define $f$ on the basis $\mathcal B$ by $f(x_0) = \Vert x_ 0 \Vert$ and $f(x_i)= 0$ for $i \in I$.

For any vector $x=\lambda_0 x_0 + \sum_{j \in J \subseteq I} \lambda_j x_j$ where $J$ is a finite subset of $I$, we have

$$\vert f(x) \vert = \vert \lambda_0 f(x_0) \vert = \vert \lambda_0 \vert \Vert x_0 \Vert \le \Vert x \Vert.$$

From which the expected result follows

$$\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in X,\Vert x \Vert \le 1 \, ,x\neq 0\}=1$$ by modifying the $\sup$ of your question.

Comment: ah yes that supremum thank you

Answer (score 1):

This would be more suitable as a comment, but I am not allowed to comment here.  There does not exist a linear function with

$$ \sup\{|f(x)|:x\in X,x\neq 0\}=1$$

Since you can always scale up $x$ by a positive real to get a bigger $|f(x)|$. The set $\{|f(x)|:x\in X,x\neq 0\}$ is not bounded above.

Did you mean $$\frac{|f(x)|}{||x||}$$ perhaps?